# How to display default value from the database

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get data from the database then display the data in input form as default. I'm using angularjs `$http get method` to retrieve the data but failed.

My laravel route

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api', 'before' => 'csrf'), function() {
    Route::get('student', function() {
        $name = Student::where('name')->first();

        return Response::json($name);
    });
}
```

Angularjs

```
.controller('syncApiCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, Module, $http) {
    $http.get('api/student').success(function(data) {
        $scope.name = data;     
        console.log(data);
    });

...
```

I would like to get the name from the Student table but the result return to me is something like

Result

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Student::where('name')->first();` is incorrect. If you want to retrieve the name of the first student do `Student::first()->name;`, but consider that `Student::first()` can be null if the database table is empty.

Comment: I did try this but still doesn't work. I also tried `DB::table('student')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->first();` but no work.

Comment: You don't need to. Try these steps:

1.- Check the Student exists and you can access it by executing `php artisan tinker` on the project's root folder and once there `Student::first()`.
2.- Check the API response value by checking the requests using your web browser inspect mode when doing the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('student', function() {
        $name = Student::first()->name;

        return Response::json($name);
    });
});
```